# Nifi :Reading from MySQL database gives Error: org.apache.nifi.reporting.InitializationException: Can't load Database Driver

Tags: etl, apache-nifi

I have been trying to read data from a Mysql Database with Nifi. But the configuration gives error saing `org.apache.nifi.reporting.InitializationException: Can't load Database Driver`.

The log is shown below.

```
2020-12-04 14:14:50,165 ERROR [Timer-Driven Process Thread-5] o.a.n.c.s.StandardControllerServiceNode Failed to invoke @OnEnabled method of DBCPConnectionPool[id=2c88a867-0176-1000-e9a7-198529e6e7dd] due to org.apache.nifi.reporting.InitializationException: Can't load Database Driver

Vishnu.chalil@COK-A-00019 MINGW64 /d/RSC/nifi-1.12.1/logs
$ tail nifi-app.log  --lines=50
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:304)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:835)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.driver
        at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:436)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:588)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:415)
        at org.apache.nifi.dbcp.DBCPConnectionPool.getDriverClassLoader(DBCPConnectionPool.java:456)
        ... 16 common frames omitted
2020-12-04 14:14:20,160 ERROR [Timer-Driven Process Thread-8] o.a.n.c.s.StandardControllerServiceNode Failed to invoke @OnEnabled method of DBCPConnectionPool[id=2c88a867-0176-1000-e9a7-198529e6e7dd] due to org.apache.nifi.reporting.InitializationException: Can't load Database Driver
2020-12-04 14:14:20,658 INFO [Flow Service Tasks Thread-2] o.a.nifi.controller.StandardFlowService Saved flow controller org.apache.nifi.controller.FlowController@1992976b // Another save pending = false
2020-12-04 14:14:39,842 INFO [pool-12-thread-1] o.a.n.c.r.WriteAheadFlowFileRepository Initiating checkpoint of FlowFile Repository
2020-12-04 14:14:39,869 INFO [pool-12-thread-1] o.a.n.wali.SequentialAccessWriteAheadLog Checkpointed Write-Ahead Log with 2036 Records and 0 Swap Files in 25 milliseconds (Stop-the-world time = 2 milliseconds), max Transaction ID 5979631
2020-12-04 14:14:39,869 INFO [pool-12-thread-1] o.a.n.c.r.WriteAheadFlowFileRepository Successfully checkpointed FlowFile Repository with 2036 records in 26 milliseconds
2020-12-04 14:14:50,164 ERROR [Timer-Driven Process Thread-5] o.a.n.c.s.StandardControllerServiceNode StandardControllerServiceNode[service=DBCPConnectionPool[id=2c88a867-0176-1000-e9a7-198529e6e7dd], versionedComponentId=null, processGroup=StandardProcessGroup[identifier=285886af-0176-1000-2ec1-fe393bb8b053,name=NiFi Flow], active=true] Failed to invoke @OnEnabled method due to org.apache.nifi.reporting.InitializationException: Can't load Database Driver: {}
org.apache.nifi.reporting.InitializationException: Can't load Database Driver
        at org.apache.nifi.dbcp.DBCPConnectionPool.getDriverClassLoader(DBCPConnectionPool.java:467)
        at org.apache.nifi.dbcp.DBCPConnectionPool.onConfigured(DBCPConnectionPool.java:406)
        at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor461.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
        at org.apache.nifi.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodsWithAnnotations(ReflectionUtils.java:142)
        at org.apache.nifi.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodsWithAnnotations(ReflectionUtils.java:130)
        at org.apache.nifi.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodsWithAnnotations(ReflectionUtils.java:75)
        at org.apache.nifi.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodsWithAnnotation(ReflectionUtils.java:52)
        at org.apache.nifi.controller.service.StandardControllerServiceNode$2.run(StandardControllerServiceNode.java:432)
        at org.apache.nifi.engine.FlowEngine$2.run(FlowEngine.java:110)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:304)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:835)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.driver
        at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:436)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:588)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:415)
        at org.apache.nifi.dbcp.DBCPConnectionPool.getDriverClassLoader(DBCPConnectionPool.java:456)
        ... 16 common frames omitted
2020-12-04 14:14:50,165 ERROR [Timer-Driven Process Thread-5] o.a.n.c.s.StandardControllerServiceNode Failed to invoke @OnEnabled method of DBCPConnectionPool[id=2c88a867-0176-1000-e9a7-198529e6e7dd] due to org.apache.nifi.reporting.InitializationException: Can't load Database Driver.
```

I will attach the screenshot of the configuratin below.

[image]

What could be the problem here?

Comment: Have you tried com.mysql.jdbc.Driver?

Comment: @Sdairs It did sove work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer was simple. The it was `com.jdbc.mysql.driver` and should have been `com.jdbc.mysql.Driver`.